# Python: How to fix parameter type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How I fix parameter type in Python?

```
def truncus(fill=int):
    return [i for i in range(fill)]
```

Comment: You can give type *hints* using annotations, but python won't enforce them.  `def truncus(fill: int)`

Comment: By "fix" do you mean "repair" or "fasten securely in place"? In other words, are you asking "my code is broken, how do I make it do what I want?" or are you asking "how do I ensure that only integers may be passed to `truncus`, and nothing else?"?

Comment: You are wasting your time, really. Just use whatever has been passed to `truncus`, and let the exception propagate - the result will be __EXACTLY__ the same as if you typechecked `fill` : it will raise a `TypeError` at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
def truncus(fill):
  if type(fill) != int:
    raise Exception("A non-integer value was passed to truncus.")
  return [i for i in range(fill)]
```

Comment: tanks, but have other way?

Comment: I think `isinstance` rather than `type() ==`.  That would allow us to, for example, specify that we want an [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable)

Comment: This should at least use `isinstance` and raise a `TypeError`

Comment: Python is dynamically typed. If you really want static typing, I'd look into a language that's statically typed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate there are cases where typecheking (correctly done typecheking I mean) makes sense. But I agree that here it's just a waste of everyone's time.